# Why does Jackson does not finish json creation from stream?

Tags: java, json, io, jackson

I am trying to write json from stream to another stream with base64 field like that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Exmaple {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(System.out);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("data");
        generator.writeBinary(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\somePath\\pdf.pdf")), -1);
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Instead of `pdf.pdf` you can use any file.

But on outut I got:

```
{"data":"JVBERi0xLjMKJcfsj6IKMzAgMCBvYmoKPD
```

- No `"` at the end despite `generator.writeEndObject()` is called
- No `=` or `==` at the end of base64
- No `}` at the end of object

Why does it happen? How to fix this???

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You might want to `close` the `JsonGenerator`.

Comment: Yep close - is the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is needed to add `generator.close()` call which leads to flush stream.